# getting ipython3 to use readline in ubuntu linux

Tags: python, ipython, readline

I have a `python3.3.1` installation on `ubuntu` (though the default is python2.6.5).I generally work using the `virtualenvwrapper`.

I wanted to install `ipython` which supports `python3`.So I did this

```
>>workon envpy331
(envpy331)damon@ubuntu:~$
(envpy331)damon@ubuntu:~$pip install ipython
....
```

After the installation was done,I tried

```
(envpy331)damon@ubuntu:ipython3
(envpy331)damon@ubuntu:

WARNING: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 19 2013, 11:41:37) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
WARNING: Readline services not available or not loaded.WARNING: The auto-indent feature requires the readline library
```

Seeing this I tried to install readline

```
(envpy331)damon@ubuntu:pip install readline
```

This downloaded and tried to install readline but failed

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

When I tried to locate libncurses,I found that version 5 is installed in the system

```
:locate libncurses

>>/lib/libncurses.so.5
/lib/libncurses.so.5.7
/lib/libncursesw.so.5
/lib/libncursesw.so.5.7
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libncurses_plugin.so
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw5/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw5.shlibs
```

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the `ncurses` libraries, but not the developement headers needed to compile `readline`.

Try installing `libncurses5-dev`, then it should work.